# Using tuple type in Angular template

Tags: angular, templates, tuples

How to use tuple type in angular template? I have two properties declared in controller:

```
export enum DisplayMode1 {
    Edit = 'Edit',
    Decided = 'Decided',
    PartsRequested = 'PartsRequested'
};
export enum DisplayMode2 {
    Edit = 'Edit',
    Submitted = 'Submitted',
    Returned = 'Returned'
};

displayMode: [
    DisplayMode1,
    DisplayMode2,
  ];
DisplayModes = [
    DisplayMode1,
    DisplayMode2,
  ];
```

```
<h3
      *ngIf="            
        displayMode !== [DisplayModes[0].Decided, DisplayModes[1].Submitted]
      "
    >
```

When I try to work with them in the template, I'm getting build error:

Property 'Submitted' does not exist on type 'typeof DisplayMode1 | typeof DisplayMode2'.
Property 'Submitted' does not exist on type 'typeof DisplayMode1'.

218         displayMode !== [DisplayModes[0].Decided, DisplayModes[1].Submitted]

However, if I use in template the DisplayModes[].Edit, which is common for both display modes, it works.

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fevsxz) U defined but you didn't initialize at init of page. You should control if there is in if condition. And you cant compare tuples like that. You should check each item one to one.

```
<h3 *ngIf="displayMode && DisplayModes && !(displayMode[0] == DisplayModes[0] && displayMode[1]==DisplayModes[1])"></h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DisplayModes = [
    DisplayMode1,
    DisplayMode2,
  ] as const; // will fix your main error
```

the other problem I noticed is `displayMode !== [DisplayModes[0].Decided, DisplayModes[1].Submitted]`. it will never work, because arrays are compared by references. so you need to do smth like `displayMode[0] !== DisplayModes[0].Decided && displayMode[1] !== DisplayModes[1].Submitted`